# How to have parent of different type?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

We have a classical data structure of posts and comments.
We manage it in ES with two doctype(post and comment) and with a parent/child relation between this (comments are child of post).

```
mapping = {
        "posts" : {
            "_id":{"path":"id"},
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type":"string"},
                "page": {"type":"string"},
                "post_type": {"type":"string"},                      
                "content":{"type":"string"}

                },
            } 
        },
        "comments":{
            "_id":{"path":"id"},
            "_parent": {"type": "posts" },
            "_routing" : {
                "required" : True,
                "path" : "parent"
            },
            "properties": {
                "id" : {"type": "string" },
                "page": {"type":"string"},
                "parent":{"type":"string"}, 
                "message" : {"type": "string" }
            }
        }
    }`
```

However we would like to have some comments that are comment on comment not on post (usual schema)

However it seems imposible to have a doctype for which parent may be of two different doctype...
Is it possible to have this in ES ?
What is the good way to manage that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need nested type in this case:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html